# Simple query with fetch

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data

I need a simple query to get me user By id with fetched bookedPlaces, this is what I have:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.bookedPlaces WHERE u.userId = (:id)")
public User findByUserIdAndFetchBookedPlacesEagerly(@Param("id") int id);
```

What this query does its find me that user, but if he don't have booked place user will **null**.
Question is how to query that will find user by id and make fetch with bookedPlaces?

Comment: Do you mean that it works when there are bookedplaces? So the problem is if there are no bookedplaces, the query returns nothing, right?

If that is the case, could you try using a left outer join?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.bookedPlaces WHERE u.userId = (:id)")
```

Did the job.